# How can my local DNS server resolve domain name?

Tags: linux, networking, dns

`Ubuntu`

I'm confused about the fact that `nslookup google.com 127.0.0.53` works perfectly and responds:

```
$ nslookup google.com 127.0.0.53
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.17.46
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4019:807::200e
```

To avoid any sort of caching involved I tried some random domain names and was surprised that `127.0.0.53` can resolve all of the names. How is that possible?

Comment: Either your machine has DNS servers configured directly in the local resolver that's listening on 127.0.0.53 or it has received an upstream DNS server from your local network via DHCP.

Comment: what OS do you have installed? you probably have DNSMasq or something similar installed. most modern linuxes use a local port, which is configured to use the network connections DNS server setting if available (I believe so it can support AVAHI mDNS).

Comment: @megamorf How can I check what DNS server was received by DHCP? Where is this configuration stored? I checked `ifconfig`, but the corresponding network interface does not have any related info

Comment: Try running `resolvectl status` if you are on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be very simple:

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 127.0.0.53
systemd-r   779 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4  27469      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.53:53 
systemd-r   779 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  27470      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
```

Run

```
$ systemd-resolve --help
```

to understand how to use it.

Then execute

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
```

to get all of the resolve status. Under my network interface there is a section

```
DNS Servers: 100.100.100.100
```

To set dns-server for the `eth0` network interface run:

```
$ sudo systemd-resolve --interface=eth0 --set-dns=200.200.200.200
```